# Why does Jetty send Set-Cookie header when accessing a path not configured with <session-config/<cookie-config>?

Tags: cookies, jetty, session-cookies, jsessionid

I have this configured in my `web.xml`:

```
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>JSESSIONID-A</name>
        <path>/pathA</path>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
```

This works, and when I go to `http://myserver/pathA/`, I can see the cookie being sent properly:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID-A=1piv1lkarbc6519i8bhw9crnzy3; Path=/pathA
```

However, when accessing a path like `http://myserver/` which should not be affected by the `<cookie-config>` setting above, Jetty also sends the cookie `JSESSIONID-A` with `Path=/pathA`:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID-A=172kf3dtw84w9atjxhidbby8l4; Path=/pathA
```

Why does this happen and is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Jetty version is 9.4.46.v20220331

Answer (score 1):

Per Servlet Spec, the `Set-Cookie` with `JSESSIONID` will be created when your code uses `HttpServletRequest.getHttpSession()`

The `<session-config>` only allows you to tweak how that cookie is managed, not restrict which paths it can occur on.

Your code dictates which HTTP/URI paths it will occur on.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, when you said "your code uses HttpServletRequest.getHttpSession()" and "Your code dictates which HTTP/URI paths it will occur on", do you mean Jetty's code? Since I don't call `getHttpSession()` manually anywhere

Comment: There would never be a `Set-Cookie` with `JSESSIONID` unless your code (in other words, your webapp `WEB-INF/classes`, and your `WEB-INF/lib`, not Jetty) used `HttpServletRequest.getHttpSession()`.

Comment: I see, I think it could be struts that's calling it? Also I notice this seems to happen when I request a JSP page, but not when requesting a non-JSP resource.